# How can I make it such that two users cannot add the same product Id to a shopping cart

Tags: express, shopping-cart, mern

I would like to edit the router such that the product Id of any given product can only be chosen by one user at a time.

```
router.get('/add-to-cart/:id', function(req, res, next) {
var productId = req.params.id;
var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {});

Product.findById(productId, function(err, product) {
   if (err) {
       return res.redirect('/');
   }
    cart.add(product, product.id);
    req.session.cart = cart;
    console.log(req.session.cart);
    res.redirect('/');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to go through all the "active" carts to see if the given product ID is already included in one of them.